# I am stuck somewhere i couldn't find

Tags: java

I dont understand why i am not able to read from the file.I am always getting **null** with **Readline()** method of **BufferedReader** .

TestStudent class should be able to perform the following functions:

Create an ArrayList object of Student objects called studentList, using the student data stored in a text file named students.txt (you should create this file such that it stores the student name and ID of several students initially – one line per student)
Allow the user to add as many new Student objects as the user requests to the ArrayList ensuring that each student has a unique student ID
When the user has finished adding new students to the list, the program will override the students.txt file such that it includes the data relating to the new students as well as the original ones
Ability to display a full list of students as well as just the existing student IDs when necessary

*Here's what i have done till now.*

```
  import java.util.*;
  import java.io.*;
  import java.io.File;
  import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
  import java.util.Scanner;
  import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class TestStudent {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File f=new File("C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\Students.txt");
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));
    // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
    FileReader fileReader = 
        new FileReader(f);

    // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
        new BufferedReader(fileReader);
   //File f=new File("Student.txt");
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(f);
    ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>(); 
    String cont;
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter Student Name:");
        String name=sc.next();
        System.out.println("Enter Student ID:");
        String id=sc.next();
        bw.write(name);
        bw.write("\t"+id);
        bw.newLine();

        System.out.println("Continue Adding?");
        cont=sc.next();
     }
     while(cont.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));





     while(bufferedReader.readLine() != null){
        String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
        String[] record = line.split("\t");
        Student myStudent =new Student(record[0],record[1]);

        studentList.add(myStudent);
    }

    for(Student st:studentList)
        System.out.println(st.Name+" "+st.Id);

    bw.close();
    scan.close();
    sc.close();

        }
    }

    class Student{

        String Name, Id;                                    
    with default value red

    Student(String string, String string0) {
        System.out.println("s"); 
    }

//Following are Mutators methos
public String getName() {
    return this.Name;

        }

public String getId() {
    return this.Id;
        }


//Following are accessor Methods
public void setName(String s){
    this.Name=s;

 }

public void setID(String ID) {
    this.Id = ID;
}




public String toString() {                                    
        return "Student name is "+getName()+" Student Id is "+getId();

      }

public boolean isValidID() {                                    
        if(getId().length()!=6)
            return false;
            else{
                 for(int i=0;i<getId().length();i++){
                    if(Id.charAt(i)>'9'||Id.charAt(i)<'0')
                        return false;
                    }  
        return true;
      }
   }


   public boolean IDExists(Student other) {                                    
            if(other.getId().equals(this.getId()))
                return true;
            else
                return false;

          }


}
```

Comment: Opening the file for writing truncates its contents. There are so many things wrong with this code, it isn't possible to list them all. You need to develop code one small piece at a time. Make sure that piece works before you move on to the next piece. Use a [minimal, complete, verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example when you ask a question. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
while(bufferedReader.readLine() != null){
    String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
     ...
}
```

The first call to `readLine()` reads the line, but does not assign it - its lost. The next call to `readLine()` reads the *next* line.

It should be:

```
String line = null;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
   ....
}
```

This reads the next line, assign it to `line`, and then compares to `null`.

Then, your student constructor is broken:

```
Student(String string, String string0) {
    System.out.println("s"); 
}
```

You never assign `string` and `string0` to anything, and `Id` and `Name` are not assigned and always `null`.

Your code furthermore does not compile:

```
 String Name, Id;                                    
    with default value red
```

This is a syntax error.

Read about [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to ensure your code is working and your question focused on one problem at a time. Most of your problems would be gone simply by making sure you test every part of your program separately and make sure it actually compiles.

Answer (score -1):

you forgot to assign studentID and studentName for new Object in constructor

```
Student(String string, String string0) {
  System.out.println("s");
  id = string;
  name = string0;        
}
```

and because you write and read the same file so you must close fileWriter before reading

```
 do {
    // your code
 }
 while(cont.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
 // close buffer writer before reading
 bw.close()
 String line;
 while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){

    String[] record = line.split("\t");
    Student myStudent =new Student(record[0],record[1]);

    studentList.add(myStudent);
}
```